# How to write this domain to be sure at 100 % that we will get the right stock pack operation for each invoice line?

Tags: odoo-10

This post should be a little more complex than usual.

We have created a new field for an account.invoice.line : pack_operation. With this field, we can print serial/lot number for each line on the PDF invoice (this part works well).

Many hours passed trying to write the domain to select the EXACT and ONLY stock pack operation for each invoice line.

In the code below, we used the domain [('id','=', 31)] to make our tests printing the PDF.

Ho to write this domain to be sure at 100 % that we will get the right stock pack operation for each invoice line?

I really need your help here... Too complex for my brain.
Our code :

```
class AccountInvoiceLine(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.invoice.line"
    pack_operation = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='stock.pack.operation', compute='compute_stock_pack_operation_id')

    def compute_stock_pack_operation_id(self):       
         stock_operation_obj = self.env['stock.pack.operation']
         stock_operation = stock_operation_obj.search(            [('id','=', 31)]            )
         self.pack_operation = stock_operation[0]




   EDIT#1
I know that you won't like my code. But, this one seems to work. I take any comments and improvements with pleasure.



    class AccountInvoiceLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice.line"
    pack_operation = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='stock.pack.operation', compute='compute_stock_pack_operation_id')@api.one
    def compute_stock_pack_operation_id(self):


        procurement_order_obj = self.env['procurement.order']
        stock_operation_obj = self.env['stock.pack.operation']

        all_picking_ids_for_this_invoice_line = []


        for saleorderline in self.sale_line_ids:

            for procurement in saleorderline.procurement_ids:

                for stockmove in procurement.move_ids:

                    if stockmove.picking_id.id not in all_picking_ids_for_this_invoice_line
                        all_picking_ids_for_this_invoice_line.append(stockmove.picking_id.id)


        all_picking_ids_for_this_invoice_line))

        stock_operation = stock_operation_obj.search(
            [ '&', 
                ('picking_id','in',all_picking_ids_for_this_invoice_line),
                ('product_id','=',self.product_id.id)
                ]
            )

        self.pack_operation = stock_operation[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pack_operation` field is a computed field, that be default means that the field will not be saved on the database unless you set `store=True` when you define your field.

So, what you can do here is change:

```
pack_operation = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='stock.pack.operation', compute='compute_stock_pack_operation_id')
```

to:

```
pack_operation = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='stock.pack.operation', compute='compute_stock_pack_operation_id', store=True)
```

And try running your query again.